# Calculating Fourier series of infinite sum in two ways

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be in the Schwartz class. Show that $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}f(2\pi n)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\hat{f}(k)$$ by calculating the Fourier series of $$F(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}f(x-2\pi n)$$ in two ways.

The Fourier coefficients of $F(x)$ are $$\hat{F}(n)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi F(x)e^{-inx}dx=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \left(\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}f(x-2\pi k)\right)e^{-inx}dx$$ How can we continue from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you COULD look it up here: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Poisson_Summation_Formula

Comment: If you give a link-only reference, a link to an answer on MSE would be a step toward self containment. Here are a couple of proofs on MSE: [Poisson's summation formula](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/183577) and [proof of Poisson formula by T. Tao](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/296537).

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$
F(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}f(x+2n\pi)
$$
then
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\hat{f}(k)
&=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,e^{-ikx}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1{2\pi}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_{(2n-1)\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi} f(x)\,e^{-ikx}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1{2\pi}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x+2n\pi)\,e^{-ikx}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1{2\pi}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_{-\pi}^\pi F(x)\,e^{-ikx}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\hat{F}(k)\\[4pt]
&=F(0)\\[8pt]
&=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}f(2n\pi)
\end{align}
$$